# How to pass info from client to onCreateUser callback in Meteor with accounts-ui

Tags: meteor

1) A visitor comes to my website

2) The visitor does X, which I store to the `Session` or localStorage

3) That visitor creates an account

I want to store X on the user object. I feel like I need to do this using `Accounts.onCreateUser`, but I can't access the session from the server. Any ideas?

Comment: Its possible to store X on the user document?

If yes just store X on the profile field on the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, figured out a super simple workaround...

Instead of saving X onto the user object immediately when an account is created, I just set it to `localStorage` and check that cookie in `Meteor.startup` if the user has created an actual account.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar pattern in our app, however we are controlling the registration process and calling `Accounts.createUser` from the client ourselves. In the *callback* from `Accounts.createUser` we read the session variable and then update the user doc.

*However*, one can also modify the *profile* object before calling `Accounts.createUser` and using that object to pass through a variable from *Session*.

Comment: is this possible with `accounts-ui` though? I don't get direct access to `Accounts.createUser` with that package.

Comment: No, you'd have to do your own UI. We wanted more control over the UX in our app so this gave us the opportunity to follow the pattern above. An altenative approach for you: pass X to the server using a Meteor.call() and store it in a closure. Then in Accounts.onCreateUser() (server-side), use that closure to modify the profile key of the user document.